# Get mails from iphone settings

Tags: objective-c, ios, email

there any way to get my personal email accounts created in the iphone settings ??

I am making an application to send mail and would like to select one of the email accounts I have on my iPhone to send and then select the destianatorios of my agenda.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but iOS offers several ways to display an email composition view controller, as well as methods to access the contacts a user has saved on his /her iDevice.

To display a mail composition view, make a weak link to the `MessageUI.framework` in your project (a weak link is preferred since the `MessageUI.framework` is not available on very old iOS versions), then do something like this:

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil) {
    // MessageUI Library is available. Presenting modal mail composer view.
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailViewController setSubject:@"This is the subject of the email"];
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"This is the body of the email." isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
    [mailViewController release];
} else {
    // MessageUI Library not available. Opening mail.app using a URL scheme.
    //  Note that this URL scheme only works on iOS3 and below, and seems to only accept a 
    //  limited number of characters. For this reason, we only attach the URL.
    NSString *mailBody = @"This is the body of the email."
    NSString *mailSchemeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?body=%@", mailBody];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mailSchemeURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
}
```

If you want to access contacts on the iDevice, link `AddressBook.framework` into your project. You can access the values on the device by following the instructions in [Apple's programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html). For example, you can get an array of all contacts like so:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *contacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

I expect you can instantiate a mail composition view with a specific contact by using a combination of the above. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but MFMailComposeViewController i cant select the user that send the email... In my settings i have one hotmail account and one gmail account and i want to send an email only with one count and i want select that user count.

Comment: @JaviLesPaul - just tap on the from field, this then opens up the cc and bcc fields and also makes the from field editable - another tap allows you to select from your from accounts. You aren't going to be able to access the mail settings from within your app, it's outside the sandbox.

Comment: Ah, I see. So to clarify, you want to specify the email account which is used to *send* the email. As far as I know, the account used to send the email will always be the one specified in `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Default Account`. I may be wrong, but I also wonder whether it would be a good idea to ignore user preferences when sending email. In any case, sorry I couldn't help!